# "Unsupported field value" when saving data into Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Received this error when I am trying to save data into the firestore.
using firebase 9.2
Below Images contains the data object.
[image]

> FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function (found in document `collectionId`/`docId`)

It works and gives no error whenever I newly refresh, but as soon as I update data and save it into the firestore, the above Error throws.

I tried with `setDoc` function too, but it gives the same error msg .

Not able to understand what's so wrong in the data field, checked manually too and it doesn't have any difference.

```
const onSave = async(nodes,edges)=>{
        // const element = document.createElement('a');
        // const {nodes,edges} = reactFlowInstance.toObject();
        // this will run when user hit the save button
        // nodes and edges are coming from react Flow library 
        const data={
          initialNodes:nodes,
          initialEdges:edges
        }
        try{
          await saveToDatabase(data);
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log("error in saving into the firestore",err);
        }

async function saveToDatabase(data){
    // saving to database things happens here and
    if(!currentUser) return 
    console.log(data);
    var fileName = prompt("Enter the name of file");
    while(await checkDatabaseFiles(fileName)){
        console.log("Give different file name")
        window.alert("Choose different file name")
        fileName = prompt("Enter the name of file");
    }
    await setDoc(doc(db,currentUser.uid,fileName),{
        timestamp:serverTimestamp(),
        data:data,
        fileName:fileName
    });
    fetchFromDatabase(currentUser)
}
```

Comment: How is the `data` object in your code initialized? --- Keep in mind: we can only see what you shared, and have no way of knowing where you get values from outside of that. Make sure that the we can copy/paste the code you shared to reproduce the exact error you get. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added some code that might help.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, as we have no way to know what values you pass to `onSave`. All we can see is what the error message says: you're passing an object that has functions, which can't be written to the database.

Comment: Anyone of you guys receiving this type of error. Try to use sanitize  the data by const sanitizedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(data)).                                                                   USE this I tried this before but didn't see it working maybe didn't remove the browser caching or something.

Comment: You use this "use sanitize the data by const sanitizedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(data))." to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes,Dominic.....